# Implementing Heap Sort with java objects

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, arraylist, heapsort

I have been given the task of implementing a heap sort using java. The sorting will be by the annual salary but the object employee will accept both a string for name and an int for salary. I have been successful with bubblesort with basically the same classes but I am having some trouble with the heap sort. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Company {



//create a default heap using array list
private ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();

/* Add a new object into the binary heap */
//building a heap

public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    list.add(employee); //append to the heap
}

public Employee remove() {
int count = 0;
if (list.isEmpty())
    return null;

Employee removedObject = list.get(0);
list.set(0, list.get(list.size() - 1));
list.remove(list.size() - 1);

int currentIndex = 0;
while (currentIndex < list.size()) {
    int leftChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 1;
    int rightChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 2;

    // find the maximum between the two children
    if (leftChildIndex >= list.size())
        break; // the tree is a heap

    int maxIndex = leftChildIndex;
    if (rightChildIndex < list.size()) {
        if (list.get(maxIndex).compareTo(list.get(rightChildIndex)) < 0) {
            maxIndex = rightChildIndex;
            count++;
        }
    }
    // swap if the current node is less than the maximum
    if (list.get(currentIndex).compareTo(list.get(maxIndex)) < 0) {
        Employee temp = list.get(maxIndex);
        list.set(maxIndex, list.get(currentIndex));
        list.set(currentIndex, temp);
        currentIndex = maxIndex;
        count++;

    }
    else
        break;
}
// This is what I changed.
//list.add(0, removedObject);
//count++;
System.out.println(count);
return removedObject;

}


        /*
         * Method to print all elements in the ArrayList
         */

        public void listEmployees(){
            for (Employee employee : list)
                System.out.println(employee.toString());
            System.out.println();
        }

        public void listEmployeesSorted() {
            ArrayList<Employee> copy = new ArrayList<Employee>(list);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while (list.size()>0) {
                Employee e = this.remove();
                builder.append(e.toString()+"\n");
            }
            this.list = copy;
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) { 

            /*
             * Instantiate object and call it 'direct'
             */   
            Company direct = new Company();

            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner Declaration
            String name;
            int salary;

            /*
             * Enter all the employee data
             */
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("John Hughes",36100));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Stephen Hughes",22100));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Michael Smith", 0));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Ludmilia Petrushevskaya", 120120));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Amy Gu", 36100));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Marta Villanueva Cortez", 34020));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Ian Palmer-Jones", 23090));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Andrew Andrews", 220100));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Andy Rainsford", 67000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Bob Bobsworth", 23000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Paul Smith", 29000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("James James", 23023));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Henry Cooper", 33900));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Ian Paisley", 33901));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Alan Ball", 45000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Mick Channon", 55600));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Paul Halibut", 26780));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Raj Patel", 33090));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Mary James", 23000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Alison Frogget", 78100));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Jenny Eclair", 40000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Sasha Lane", 21000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Sarah Milligan", 100300));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Zico", 120000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Pippa Forester", 90000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Angela Landsdowne", 8000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Emily Taxem", -1000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Jill Beans", 654000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Alan Salt", 33333));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Imran Khan", 87000));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Matt Demon", 66666));
            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Douglas Adams", 42000));

            System.out.println("\tName\t\t Salary");
            direct.listEmployees();//print out all elements in ArrayList before sorting
            System.out.println("\tName\t\t Salary");
            System.out.println("__________________________________________________");              
            direct.listEmployeesSorted();//print out all elements in ArrayList after sorting

            /*
             * Use scanner to get user input (name,salary) to be entered into
             * the existing sorted list
             */

            System.out.print("Please enter a new employee's name: ");
            name=input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the employee's associated salary: ");
            salary=input.nextInt(); 

            direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp(name,salary));
            direct.listEmployeesSorted();
        }//end main


}//end class Company
```

For a small number of data it sorts well, but when i start adding negative numbers or 0 or even sometimes just normal positive values the whole sort gets crazy. I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this. I know for a fact it is the implementation of my heap sort methods that is giving the problem, everything else should be fine...lol...please assist

this is the employee class:

```
public abstract class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
private String name;
private int salary;  

/*
 * Two-Arguement Constructor
 */

 Employee(String name, int salary){
  this.name = name;
   this.salary = salary;
 }//end method
    public int getSalary(){
    return salary;
   }//end method

  /*
     * Return the employee's name
      */

 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }//end method


/*
 * Return the compareTo
 */

public int compareTo(Employee x){
if (this.salary < x.salary)
    return -1;
else if (this.salary > x.salary)
    return 1;
else 
    return 0;
}//end method
public String toString(){        
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();        
buffer.append("\t");
buffer.append(getName());
buffer.append("\t  ");
buffer.append(getSalary());
buffer.append("\t  ");
return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

and this is the sub class that implements employee:

```
class EmployeeImp extends Employee{

EmployeeImp(String name, int salary) {
    super(name, salary);
}
}
```

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Please be more specific than "gets crazy". What exactly is going on?

Comment: @Dukeling terribly sorry still getting a hang of stackoverflow...aite leme post the output in the question

Comment: @rlinden as you can see the negative isnt where its supposed to be as are the other numbers. can you help fix my heap sort method?...i found code online about heap sort but none implemented objects with like a string and an int so it was confusing to transfer that logic here

Comment: When you add an element, you try to use the last index. If I remember my heapsort correctly, the largest/smallest element is the right most element. This may not always be the last index. Shouldn't you insert elements from the top (index 0)?

Comment: Employee compareTo is the problem (I think). Can you post the Employee code?

Comment: i tink the compareTo method seems alright @Justin

Comment: You could use a java PriorityQueue (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) with a custom Comparator<Employee> instead of your home baked heap to have the desired behavior. Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: @Jamal Yea, it looks fine o me also.

Comment: `x.salary`Is it OK? Are you accessing a private member directly?

Comment: I was told not to use priority queues as it will be used in a later task...i implemented bubble sort in the same way and it sorted fine...which is why i tink the problem is in the heap sort method.. @Giodude

Comment: @Averroes if by that you mean i declared salary to be private and that it will be accessed directly from hard coding then yes...unless you mean something else?

Comment: Since this is a learning task, I recommend you read about heaps and heapsort in some textbook. CLRS spells it out clearly and you can basically use their pseudocode to write java code very easily (I've done it several times for many of their algos). Make your algorithm work with an array of integers first and then when you're confident about it, refactor the code to sort instances of your class. The next step would be to sort any object for which a comparator is specified.

Comment: I mean if salary is private in Employee how can you do x.salary?

Comment: I don't think this question can help anyone but @Jamal

Comment: @Jamal you don't understand heapsort. You need to completely empty the heap to get the sorted order. direct.listEmployees() will never list them in sorted order.

Comment: @Jamal you will have to call "direct.remove()" as many times as you call "direct.add()" to get them in sorted order.

Comment: @Justin i call them 33 times (how many times i enter direc.add) and now all the data is gone. how do i print them now?...because each time it removes it removes the largest numbers, 2nd largest and so on...my question is where did they go and how do i print them out?

Comment: @Jamal It's the nature of the heap, you cannot print them in sorted order AND keep them in the heap without writing a custom print method which isn't an easy task. Although, you could print the heap by removing all the elements then add them all back in before your return.

Comment: @Jamal Actually, now that I think about it; you can just copy the array before you remove all then just replace the list with the copy. I'll add that print method to my answer.

Comment: @Justin thanks alot. one last question though..im confused how to implement the toString method. so do i direct.toString(); then direct.toString();...etc...or are you asking me to replace to toString method i have in my employee class?

Comment: @Justin no sorry i don't think your telling me to replace to tostring method in the employee class

Comment: @Jamal the toString method is for the "Company" class. So, you should only have to do direct.toString() once and get the whole list of employees in sorted order.

Comment: @Justin so once i do direct.toString once then i can proceed to do the 33 direct.remove();? and then how to do i print the sorted array? listEmployees();?

Comment: @Jamal the toString() will print the employees in a sorted order.... AND it will allow you to still remove the employees whenever needed.

Comment: @Justin this is what i did 
.
.
.
direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Matt Demon", 66666));     
                
                System.out.println("\tName\t\t Salary");
                direct.listEmployees();//print out all elements in ArrayList before sorting
                System.out.println("\tName\t\t Salary");
                System.out.println("__________________________________________________");
                direct.toString();

its giving me the list before sorting and thats it...the sorted list isnt shown

Comment: Try this:  System.out.println(direct.toString());

Comment: nope doesnt work....still only shows the unsorted array...if i put direct.toString() after the last direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Matt Demon", 66666)); is that sufficient?...or do i still need to put the direct.remove(); 33 times?

Comment: direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Matt Demon", 66666));
System.out.println("\tName\t\t Salary");
direct.listEmployees();
System.out.println("\tName\t\t Salary"); 
System.out.println("__________________________________________________");
System.out.println(direct.toString());

Comment: @Justin does the program work for you?....because it doesn't for me

Comment: can you edit my code so i can where i went wrong...because i've done everything you've mentioned so i don't know where i went wrong @Justin

Comment: @Jamal ok, I edited it. I've added a new method listEmployeesSorted() and changed your main()

Comment: please check above in my question i posted a pic of what im getting...@Justin

Comment: @Justin i got it to work now thanks alot...one question though...i need to increment a counter and print it...and the listEmployeesSorted() includes the printing of the remove() method which i put the System.out.print(count) at the end...do you know how i can get solve this?...it prints all the steps when it calls the remove() which is like 33 times...thanks alot btw...you method listEmployeesSorted() was very helpful, i fixed my add method and added two other methods and it worked a charm...the remove() stayed the same though...

Comment: @Jamal You will just have to have two methods; one which prints and one that doesn't

Comment: @Justin what do you mean?...could you explain further?...i should have one listEmployeesSorted() that prints and another that doesn't?

Comment: @Justin do you think if i declare a private static int count; outside of the remove method, then count++ inside the method, then system.out.println(count) in the listExmployeesSorted() it would give the appropriate count?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your problem; why are you doing this at the end of remove?

```
list.add(0, removedObject);
count++;
```

Should it be removed?

```
//list.add(0, removedObject);
//count++;
```

I've made the change above on a local copy of your code (changed Employee to not be abstract) and it seems to be working fine. I've used this validatino code below to check using random data.

```
public boolean validate() {
    Employee p = this.remove();
    while (list.size()>0) {
        Employee e = this.remove();
        if (e.compareTo(p)>0) return false;
        p = e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Testing code.

```
    boolean result = false;
    for (int x=0; x<100; x++) {
        int size = 100000;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            int r = RANDOM.nextInt();
            company.addEmployee(new Employee(String.valueOf(r),r));
        }
        result = company.validate();
        if (result==false) break;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Here is the full remove method:

```
public Employee remove() {
    int count = 0;
    if (list.isEmpty())
        return null;

    Employee removedObject = list.get(0);
    list.set(0, list.get(list.size() - 1));
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);

    int currentIndex = 0;
    while (currentIndex < list.size()) {
        int leftChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 1;
        int rightChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 2;

        // find the maximum between the two children
        if (leftChildIndex >= list.size())
            break; // the tree is a heap

        int maxIndex = leftChildIndex;
        if (rightChildIndex < list.size()) {
            if (list.get(maxIndex).compareTo(list.get(rightChildIndex)) < 0) {
                maxIndex = rightChildIndex;
                count++;
            }
        }
        // swap if the current node is less than the maximum
        if (list.get(currentIndex).compareTo(list.get(maxIndex)) < 0) {
            Employee temp = list.get(maxIndex);
            list.set(maxIndex, list.get(currentIndex));
            list.set(currentIndex, temp);
            currentIndex = maxIndex;
            count++;

        }
        else
            break;
    }
    // This is what I changed.
    //list.add(0, removedObject);
    //count++;
    System.out.println(count);
    return removedObject;

}
```

Example data... Remember, the only guarantee a (max) heap makes is the the top element will be the max in the heap AND every parent will be greater or equal to it's children.

```
Input order:                   5, 12, 12, 17, 8, 7, 4, 1, 5, 19, 
Companies internal list order: 19=19, 17=17, 12=12, 5=5, 12=12, 7=7, 4=4, 1=1, 5=5, 8=8, 
Heap sorted order:             19=19, 17=17, 12=12, 12=12, 8=8, 7=7, 5=5, 5=5, 4=4, 1=1,
```

A non destructive print method for Company (it's actually destructive but returns the initial state after it's done printing):

```
public String toString() {
    ArrayList<Employee> copy = new ArrayList<Employee>(list);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (list.size()>0) {
        Employee e = this.remove();
        builder.append(e.toString()+"\n");
    }
    this.list = copy;
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i have a sub class that extends employee called employeeimp thats why i had an abstract class... and i add data to the arraylist like this :

Company direct = new Company();
direct.addEmployee(new EmployeeImp("Jenny Eclair", 40000));

Comment: @Jamal I think this is the solution to your problem; unless you override compareTo in EmployeeImpl which could also cause problems. After making the changes to the remove() method, it seems o be working fine.

Comment: ok so just to be clear could you list down what i gta do, also could you show a screen shot of your output?

Comment: @Jamal I've added the full source of my remove method to the answer.

Comment: @Jamal How are you producing your output? You realize that the "list" inside the company will not be in sorted order, right?

Comment: let me post all my source code to me answer and you take a look again please

Comment: @Jamal The list will be "somewhat" sorted. To get the sorted output, you will have to remove() each item from the heap. I'll add an example in my answer.